# I want to execute few cmd commands from a text file by using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have created a txt file with the following commands.

```
cd..
cd <Folder location>
del *_extract.txt /Q
```

Now, I want to create a batch file that will open cmd and execute the commands mentioned in the text file.
The batch file I have created has the following content

```
@echo off
start "clear" cmd.exe -m <textfilelocation>
```

Comment: Why don't you just rename your `file.txt` to `file.bat`?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is as Stephan Said in the comment. Rename your file from `.txt` to `.cmd` or `.bat`. Then you can run it on its own, or simply `call` it from your other batch file as:

```
call "C:\Some Location\file.cmd"
```

If you really want to retain the txt file, then run a for loop:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("C:\Some path\file.txt") do %%i
```

Considering a text file with comments mayb, in this case using `#` (which is a non batch file standard) we can execute the lines that are not comments.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "C:\Some Path\file.txt" ^| findstr /v "#"') do %%i
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to rename the file to `.bat` or `.cmd` (or make a (temporary) copy).

I for some reason it just *has* to be a `.txt` file, your options are very limited.

Besides Gerhards suggestion (the one with the `for` loop), a maybe better option is to "feed" the lines of the textfile to `cmd` (not recommended; provided just for academic reasons):

```
<script.txt %comspec%
```

or without command repetition and header:

```
<script.txt %comspec% /q /k
```

NOTES:

- the lines in the script.txt have to be command-line syntax (for example `for %a ...`, not batch-file syntax `for %%a ...`)
- `GOTO` and `CALL :label` won't work (they don't work on command-line)
- a "multiline" `for` command works, but will clutter your output with a `More?` prompt per line (not suppressable).
- if delayed expansion is needed, you need to add the `/v:on` switch to the `cmd` command (`setlocal *` has no effect on the command line)

Example-`script.txt`:

```
echo off
echo/
:start [ignored]
echo hello %username%
ping -n 1 www.google.com | find "TTL="
for %a in (alpha beta) do (
  echo %a
)
goto :start [ignored]
echo done.
```

Output:

```
hello Stephan
Antwort von 172.217.21.206: Bytes=32 Zeit=12ms TTL=121
Mehr? Mehr? alpha
beta
done.
```